# Xcode Accessibility Inspector (XIB): Acceptable to use phonetic spelling for Label?

Tags: xcode, label, accessibility, xib, phonetics

I'm upgrading an iOS application for accessibility in Xcode. I'm using Interface Builder's Accessibility Inspector to set values that enable VoiceOver features for the view.

When entering a value for `Label`, is it acceptable (or even best-practice) to use phonetic spelling instead of actual spelling?

**Examples:**

Some words or product names are mispronounced by VoiceOver. For example, "Waze" isn't pronounced correctly - should I spell it "Ways?" Or "Nowait" spelled "No wait?" Or "UltraOne" spelled "Ultra one?"

Another example, should abbreviations be typed out? For example the abbreviation for Ohio (OH) is pronounced "Oh" instead of "Ohio."

Sometimes abbreviations like "FAQs" are pronounced "facks." Should I enter something like "F.A.Q.s" or "F A Qs?"

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of Accessibility Inspector]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, that's what I recommend if it can improve the user experience.

As you suggest, you can write the label with phonetic spelling directly in the Xcode interface builder or implement a [new iOS 11 feature](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-17215.html#AttributedProperties) that enables to use the International Phonetic Alphabet thanks to the [speech attributes for attributed strings](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/accessibility/uiaccessibility/speech_attributes_for_attributed_strings).